# Facebook insights API always gives no data available in this timerange

Tags: facebook-insights

I use this link:

https://www.facebookmarketingdevelopers.com/samples/adsreporting

to get results from insights api.

We have continuously running ads but I keep getting no data in this timerange no matter what date I select.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many causes, such as:

1. You are querying a wrong ad account;
2. You happened to pick dates without data;
3. The date parameter format was not correct if you used certain dates;
4. Your ads got no delivery;

None of these have a high chance. But without further information, all I can do it to guess based on nothing.